# Use puppeteer-core and installing chromium manually

Tags: chromium, puppeteer

By including the `puppeteer` package, you automatically download and install Chromium which is ~200MB download.

But puppeteer is just one component of our repo, and some users may want to clone and run commands in our repo without downloading the entire Chromium bundle. Basically, it's an opt-in subset of the repo.

Now this is all well and good, they provide the useful `puppeteer-core` package which doesn't bundle Chromium. Awesome.

But how do I manually install Chromium so that `puppeteer-core` finds it? I just get the following error no matter what I try (e.g. globally installing puppeteer).

`Chromium revision is not downloaded.`

I'm using yarn if that affects anything. A nice simple `brew` and `apt` command would be super useful here, but I'd even write a quick bash/node script to handle the installation if need be.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can manually download Chromium (e.g. via [this page](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html) or [this page](https://download-chromium.appspot.com/)) and then set the `executablePath` when launching it:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: 'path/to/your/chrome.exe'
});
```

Check out this [issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1425) on the puppeteer github repository for more information on what to download from where.